# Python: RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop (Threading & Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, click, thread-safety

I'm encountering this error when I run my code every time I understand it has something to do with threading but I'm a beginner so I do not understand much about it I tried searching on Google, StackOverflow, etc. and it hasn't been much help even without the Intervals() function it gives the same error right after it. Also, another problem is that root.mainloop() doesn't run at all and I don't understand why so I was wondering if someone more knowledgeable could help.

Full Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\Users\Programming\Python\Tools\AutoClicker.py", line 177, in run
    ClickMouse.intervals(self)
  File "c:\Users\Programming\Python\Tools\AutoClicker.py", line 151, in intervals
    h = self.hour.get()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3109, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pyautogui
import threading
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

# Window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("X's AutoClicker")
root.configure(bg="White")

# Tabs
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.place(x=0, y=0)
tab1 = Frame(notebook, width=500, height=300)
tab2 = Frame(notebook, width=500, height=300)
notebook.add(tab1, text='  Menu  ')
notebook.add(tab2, text='  Settings  ')

# Variables
delay = 0
count = 1
repeat = IntVar()
single_double_var = StringVar()
clicks_amount = StringVar()
single_double_drop = ["Single", "Double"]
single_double_var.set("Single")
repeat.set(1)
hotkey = ("a")
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char=hotkey)
press_key = "Left"


# Functionsa

def none():
    return

def settings_select():
    notebook.select(tab2)

def repeat_toggle():
    global count
    count += 1
    if count == 2:
        count = 0
        repeat.set(None)

def press_update():
    global press_key, start_stop_key
    press_key = press_entry.get()
    start_stop_key = KeyCode(char=hotkey)

def hotkey_update():
    global hotkey
    hotkey = hotkey_entry.get()

############################# TAB 1 #############################
# Title
auto = Label(tab1, text="Auto Clicker", font="Arial 20 bold", bg="White", fg="Black").place(x=150, y=2)

# Clicks
clicks = Label(tab1, text="Clicks:", font="Arial 11 bold", bg="White", fg="Black")
click = Entry(tab1, textvariable=clicks_amount, text="", font="Arial 9", width=10, borderwidth=4)
clicks.place(x=70, y=60)
click.place(x=150, y=60)
click.insert(0, "10")

# Repeat Until Stopped Circle Option
repeat_button = Radiobutton(tab1, text="Repeat Until Stopped", font="Arial 11 bold", variable=repeat, command=repeat_toggle, value=1, fg="Black", bg="White")
repeat_button.place(x=65, y=105)

# Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds
hours_label = Label(tab1, text="Hours:", font="Arial 10", bg="White", fg="Black")
minutes_label = Label(tab1, text="Mins:", font="Arial 10", bg="White", fg="Black")
seconds_label = Label(tab1, text="Seconds:", font="Arial 10", bg="White", fg="Black")
milliseconds_label = Label(tab1, text="Milliseconds:", font="Arial 10", bg="White", fg="Black")

hours_label.place(x=10, y=155)
minutes_label.place(x=109, y=155)
seconds_label.place(x=200, y=155)
milliseconds_label.place(x=321, y=155)

# Start/Stop Button
start_stop_label = Label(tab1, text="Press " + hotkey + " to Click", font="Arial 13 bold", bg="White", fg="Black", borderwidth=4)
start_stop_label.place(x=40, y=205)

# Settings
settings = Button(tab1, text="Settings", font="Arial 13 bold", bg="White", fg="Black", command=settings_select)
settings.place(x=325, y=205)

############################# TAB 2 #############################

# Press - Button To Press
press_label = Label(tab2, text="Press: ", font="Arial 11 bold", bg="White", fg="Black")
press_entry = Entry(tab2, text="Left", font="Arial 11 bold", bg="White", fg="Black", width=5, borderwidth=4)
press_label.place(x=70, y=20)
press_entry.place(x=140, y=20)

mouse_label = Label(tab2, text="️", font="Arial 40", bg="White", fg="Black")
left = Label(tab2, text="Left", font="Arial 11", bg="White", fg="Black")
right = Label(tab2, text="Right", font="Arial 11", bg="White", fg="Black")
middle = Label(tab2, text="Middle", font="Arial 11", bg="White", fg="Black")

mouse_label.place(x=390, y=30)
left.place(x=357, y=45)
right.place(x=445, y=45)
middle.place(x=392, y=15)
press_entry.insert(0, press_key)

# Hotkey - Button To Start Pressing
hotkey_label = Label(tab2, text="Hotkey: ", font="Arial 11 bold", bg="White", fg="Black")
hotkey_entry = Entry(tab2, text="", font="Arial 11 bold", bg="White", fg="Black", width=5, borderwidth=4)
hotkey_entry.insert(0, hotkey)
hotkey_label.place(x=60, y=90)
hotkey_entry.place(x=140, y=90)

# Single Or Double Presses
type_label = Label(tab2, text="Type: ", font="Arial 11 bold", bg="White", fg="Black")
single_double_drop = ["Single", "Double"]
single_double_var = StringVar()
single_double_var.set("Single")
single_double_menu = OptionMenu(tab2, single_double_var, *single_double_drop)
single_double_menu.configure(font="Arial 10 bold", borderwidth=4)
single_double_menu.place(x=120, y=142)



class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.running = False
        self.hour = Entry(tab1, text="", font="Arial 9", width=4, borderwidth=4)
        self.minute = Entry(tab1, text="", font="Arial 9", width=4, borderwidth=4)
        self.second = Entry(tab1, text="", font="Arial 9", width=4, borderwidth=4)
        self.millisecond = Entry(tab1, text="", font="Arial 9", width=4, borderwidth=4)
        self.millisecond.insert(0, "10")
        self.hour.place(x=63, y=155)
        self.minute.place(x=153, y=155)
        self.second.place(x=275, y=155)
        self.millisecond.place(x=419, y=155)

    def intervals(self):  # 1H = 3600 SECS, 1M = 60 SECS, 1S = 1S, 1S = 0.001       
        global delay
        h = self.hour.get()
        m = self.minute.get()
        s = self.second.get()
        mi = self.millisecond.get()
        if h == '':
            h = "0"
        if m == '':
            m = "0"
        if s == '':
            s = "0"
        if mi == '':
            mi = "0"
        h_to_s = int(h) * 3600
        m_to_s = int(m) * 60
        s_to_s = int(s) * 1
        mi_to_s = int(mi) * 0.001
        delay = {h_to_s} + {m_to_s} + {s_to_s} + {mi_to_s}
        print(delay)

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True
  
    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        ClickMouse.intervals(self)
        press_update()
        hotkey_update()
        while True:
            while self.running:
                if str(clicks_amount) != "":
                    clicks_amount = int(clicks_amount)

                    try:
                        if repeat.get() == 1:
                            if single_double_var2 == "Single":
                                pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, duration=delay, button=press_key)

                            if single_double_var2 == "Double":
                                pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)
                                pyautogui.click(duration= delay, clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)

                    except TclError:
                        if single_double_var2 == "Single":
                            pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)

                        if single_double_var2 == "Double":
                            pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)
                            pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)
        
click_thread = ClickMouse()
click_thread.start()
  
def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
              
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Update: Thank you but I for some reason ran into the same error again (Updated Code and Error Text)

Comment: You should not call `listener.join()` because it will block the application.  Move `root.mainloop()` to replace `listener.join()`.  But there are still other errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Python: RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

You cannot put all `tkinter` widgets outside of function without instantiated. You must put inside `ClickMouse` module

You cannot put intervals() function outside. You must put inside `ClickMouse` module and use `self`.

Use float and f-string. Cannot use operator +

Snippet:

```
class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.running = False
        self.hour = Entry(tab1, text="", font="Arial 9", width=4, borderwidth=4)
        self.minute = Entry(tab1, text="", font="Arial 9", width=4, borderwidth=4)
        self.second = Entry(tab1, text="", font="Arial 9", width=4, borderwidth=4)
        self.millisecond = Entry(tab1, text="", font="Arial 9", width=4, borderwidth=4)
        self.millisecond.insert(0, "10")
        self.hour.place(x=63, y=155)
        self.minute.place(x=153, y=155)
        self.second.place(x=275, y=155)
        self.millisecond.place(x=419, y=155)

    ....
    ....

    def intervals(self):  # 1H = 3600 SECS, 1M = 60 SECS, 1S = 1S, 1S = 0.001       
        global delay
        h = self.hour.get()
        m = self.minute.get()
        s = self.second.get()
        mi = self.millisecond.get()
        if h == '':
            h = "0"
        if m == '':
            m = "0"
        if s == '':
            s = "0"
        if mi == '':
            mi = "0"
        h_to_s = (h) * 3600
        m_to_s = (m) * 60
        s_to_s = (s) * 1
        mi_to_s = float((mi)) * 0.001
        delay = f'{h_to_s}:{m_to_s} : {s_to_s} : {mi_to_s}
```

Screenshot:

[image]